# MSDN for Windows API in Visual C++ Express 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msdn

I install Visual C++ 2008 Express to develop code using native Win32 API. However, the MSDN Express I can install with it doesn't show help on Windows API functions - but only on .NET
Even online help isn't helpful and keep linking to MFC.

How can I integrate MSDN with Windows API documentation (SDK) into my Express 2008?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft did have a complete download of the ISO for the entire MSDN library [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=7BBE5EDA-5062-4EBB-83C7-D3C5FF92A373&displaylang=en).

Hope this is what you are looking for?

Comment: I have downloaded it and it installs the MSDN Document Explorer with all of the MSDN integrated successfully. As for VS Express, when you press F1 for help it will load that MSDN version.

Answer (score 0):

You can also download the full version of Windows SDK and use H2reg to register the SDk documentations it to your VS Express documentation.